Is there a way to convert a LINQ expression to another LINQ expression?
My repository class has a few methods for operations with the database. I recently developed the FindAsync() method, which allows you to grab only a few rows from the database based on an expression.
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Orbit.Infrastructure.Repositories.Interfaces;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Orbit.Infrastructure.Repositories
{
    public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        protected readonly DbContext Context;

        public Repository(DbContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            IConfigurationSection sectNamespaces = configuration.GetSection("AllowedEntityNamespaces");
            List<string> namespacesInConfig = [];

            foreach (IConfigurationSection child in sectNamespaces.GetChildren())
            {
                namespacesInConfig.Add(child.Path);
            }

            if (namespacesInConfig.Contains(typeof(TEntity).Namespace!))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"O namespace ${typeof(TEntity).Namespace} não está habilitado!");
            }

            Context = context;
        }

        public async Task AddAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(nameof(entity));
            _ = await Context.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(entity);
        }

        public async Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(nameof(entities));
            await Context.Set<TEntity>().AddRangeAsync(entities);
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FindAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(predicate);
            return await Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return await Context.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync(params string[] navProperties)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> entities = Context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();

            foreach (string prop in navProperties)
            {
                entities = entities.Include(prop);
            }

            return await entities.ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<TEntity?> GetAsync(int id)
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(id);
            return await Context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
        }

        public async Task RemoveAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(entity);
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                _ = Context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
            });
        }

        public async Task RemoveRangeAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(entities);
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Context.Set<TEntity>().RemoveRange(entities);
            });
        }

    }
}

Up until now, in most operations where I needed to grab one or more users based on a specific criterion, I pulled in all the users (using GetAllAsync()) and only then did I filter the users using LINQ. I realized that this was not the best solution. Ideally, you would want to throw this load of pulling a few specific users into the efcore and balance the load on the application.
In my class of services I also developed a method that allows you to find a user based on a predicate and that's where the problem lies.
UserAddRequest (DTO)
using Orbit.Domain.Entities;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Orbit.Application.Dtos.Requests
{
    public class UserAddRequest
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira o nome do usuário!")]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "O nome do usuário deve ter no máximo 100 caracteres.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", ErrorMessage = "O nome do usuário só pode conter letras, números e underline.")]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; } = null!;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira o email do usuário!")]
        [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "O email do usuário deve ter no máximo 200 caracteres.")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "O email do usuário não é válido.")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string UserEmail { get; set; } = null!;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira a data de nascimento do usuário!")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Formato de data inválido.")]
        [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
        public DateOnly UserDateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira a senha do usuário!")]
        [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "A senha do usuário deve ter no máximo 200 caracteres.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$ %^&*-]).{8,}$", ErrorMessage = "A senha deve conter pelo menos uma letra minúscula, uma letra maiúscula, um caractere especial (@$!%*?&)")]
        [Display(Name = "Senha")]
        public string UserPassword { get; set; } = null!;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório.")]
        [Range(1, 31, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve estar entre 1 e 31.")]
        [Display(Name = "Dia")]
        public int Day { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório.")]
        [Range(1, 12, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve estar entre 1 e 12.")]
        [Display(Name = "Mês")]
        public int Month { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório.")]
        [Range(1, 9999, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve estar entre 1 e 9999.")]
        [Display(Name = "Ano")]
        public int Year { get; set; }

        public User ToUser()
        {
            return new User
            {
                UserName = UserName,
                UserDateOfBirth = new DateOnly(Year, Month, Day),
                UserEmail = UserEmail,
                UserPassword = UserPassword
            };
        }
    }
}

UserResponse (DTO)
using Orbit.Domain.Entities;

namespace Orbit.Application.Dtos.Responses
{
    public class UserResponse
    {
        public uint UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string UserEmail { get; set; } = null!;
        public DateOnly UserDateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string UserPassword { get; set; } = null!;
        public string? UserDescription { get; set; }
        public byte[]? UserImageByteType { get; set; }
        public string? UserProfileName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserResponse>? Followers { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserResponse>? Users { get; set; }
    }

    public static class UserExtensions
    {
        public static UserResponse ToUserResponse(this User user)
        {
            return user.ToUserResponseInternal([]);
        }

        private static UserResponse ToUserResponseInternal(this User user, List<uint> processedUserIds)
        {
            if (processedUserIds.Contains(user.UserId))
            {
                return new UserResponse
                {
                    UserId = user.UserId,
                    UserName = user.UserName,
                    UserEmail = user.UserEmail,
                    UserDateOfBirth = user.UserDateOfBirth,
                    UserPassword = user.UserPassword,
                    UserDescription = user.UserDescription,
                    UserProfileName = user.UserProfileName,
                    UserImageByteType = user.UserImageByteType,
                    Followers = [],
                    Users = []
                };
            }

            processedUserIds.Add(user.UserId);

            UserResponse response = new()
            {
                UserId = user.UserId,
                UserName = user.UserName,
                UserEmail = user.UserEmail,
                UserDateOfBirth = user.UserDateOfBirth,
                UserPassword = user.UserPassword,
                UserDescription = user.UserDescription,
                UserProfileName = user.UserProfileName,
                UserImageByteType = user.UserImageByteType,
                Followers = user.Followers.Select(u => u.ToUserResponseInternal(new List<uint>(processedUserIds))).ToList(),
                Users = user.Users.Select(u => u.ToUserResponseInternal(new List<uint>(processedUserIds))).ToList()
            };

            return response;
        }
    }
}

User model (EF Core and repository model):
namespace Orbit.Domain.Entities;

public partial class User
{
    public uint UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string UserEmail { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateOnly UserDateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string UserPassword { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? UserDescription { get; set; }

    public byte[]? UserImageByteType { get; set; }

    public string? UserProfileName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Followers { get; set; } = [];
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } = [];
}

My FindUserAsync method of the UserService class has an Expression<Func<UserResponse, bool>> as a parameter, and the FindAsync method of the repository takes an Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> as an argument. In the service class, the generic TEntity is actually the User model
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserResponse>> FindUsersAsync(Func<UserResponse, bool> predicate)
{
    // This isn't allowed. Causes compilation error
    return await _unitOfWork.User.FindAsync(predicate); 
}

How can I convert one expression to another? Is there a way to convert the expressions or use string to map? I don't have the slightest idea how to proceed from here.
I've tried to find some solutions on the internet, but I haven't found anything that I understand in the slightest bit about what's going on.
Thanks!

Check ExpressionTypeMapper, But better to do not use generic repository at all.

#1. Never use Generic Repositories with EF.  #2. Don't use repositories if the sole reason for the repository is to try and abstract EF... The biggest argument for Repositories I come across is "so that my code is not dependent on EF-isms".. Except when you introduce complexities like Expressions, those expressions must still conform to EF-isms. I.e. an expression that calls a function still won't work. So you are doing a lot of work and re-inventing the wheel for no good reason.

All generic repositories accomplish with EF is making you do a lot more work, encounter a lot more problems (both complexity and performance), and put a straight-jacket around what EF's existing Generic Repository, the DbSet<T> already provides.

@StevePy I would not judge so hard over generic repositories. I always say: EF Core is an abstraction to the database and generic repositories are an abstraction to the OR-mapper. And I have had projects where we had an generic repository implementation with EF and another generic repository implementation to a MongoDB and we could switch on a request base to switch between these implementations without affecting our business commands. So that can make sense, also for unify Unit Tests. But I know this discussion is very opinionated.

@decius Something like that would be for data layer polymorphism more-so than a Repository where there is a distinct business requirement to support two dissimilar data sources in a common way. There are certainly trade-offs for performance/flexibility which is fine when that is a requirement. The problem with 99% of Generic Repository implementations is there is no such requirement. The justification is maybe EF will be "too slow" so abstract so it can be swapped out if that is the case, or too complicated for Jr devs. It leads to a self-fulfilling prophecy by causing the problems they fear.

Are you using EF Core directly in your business services or domain objects? How do you write unit tests? Usually you abstract EF Core anyways (at least with an interface) otherwise you writing integration tests. And if you use an interface anyways, you could directly switch to a generic repository pattern-when used correctly, because you can reuse it everywhere. The Repository implementation directly uses EF Core or IQueryables, so I don´t see any performance  impact-only the extra layer of abstraction, which should not lead to significant performance decrease compared to the database calls.

What I want to say: The general advice: "Don´t use generic repositories with EF core" is not good IMHO. Its depending on your requirements. There are useful scenarios with generic repositores and EF core.

I do utilize Repositories and leverage IQueryable<T> though not using generic repositories. Repos serve as a home for low-level rules like authorization, and to make it easier to unit test. I don't use generics, I have repositories at aggregate root levels, and operations offered by repositories vary to suit the needs of the controllers or services they service.  Repo methods offered by a Customer Repo are more different than the same compared to an Order repo. Generics are suited to identical methods interchangeable by type.

Ok, you´re coming from this DDD - object oriented - approach. I´m not a big fan of DDD (yes, I know, very controversial :) ). I´m using C# more functional. And for me there is no difference if you create a Customer or a Order, its just TEntity :). The same for getting or deleting or changing TEntity. But I know, its turning into religious discussions.

I use the repository for the sake of extra abstraction. In the future I intend to incorporate Dapper into the application for some very specific queries that are very large and complex. Naturally I agree that the Repository when used without reason only becomes a barrier to performance.

@SamiDaniel, If we omit repository flood, ExpressionTypeMapper works for you?

Yes, I actually thought of a better solution. For more complex queries that involve joining data from tables into lists, etc., I'll use efcore, and simple queries like FindAsync() I'll use Dapper. It will not be necessary to have a predicate and only an index. Increases performance and heavy operations are the responsibility of efcore
